# Postgres + ulid [XX000] ERROR: Can't give out exclusive, lock is in an empty state

Tags: postgresql

There is an novel error when trying insert row.

The database is setup with https://github.com/pksunkara/pgx_ulid.
And it is using a function `gen_monotonic_ulid()` as a default.

I followed the readme guide and added the `shared_preload_libraries = 'ulid'`.
With or without this, the error still persisted.

### Setup Details

there is also postgis installed.

```
FROM postgis/postgis:${PG_MAJOR}-3.3
...
COPY postgres.conf /etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf
CMD ["postgres", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf"]
```

Comment: Had the same issue before adding shared_preload_libraries, But fixed after adding `shared_preload_libraries = 'ulid'` in `postgresql.conf` & **Restarted postgres**

Answer (score 1):

My workaround is using `gen_ulid()` instead.